# How to make Django support IETF language tag (xx-YY format)?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, opensearch

We have a Django site that supports many languages. Trying to add opensearch plug-ins support for multi-language.

[OpenSearch.org spec](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1#The_.22language.22_parameter) uses [IETF language tag (xx-YY format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag). Default Django setup uses exact matching.

- The current state, the site support only xx form anything else return E404. Example:

  ```
  http://website.domain/en/...
  ```

Depending on user configuration the browser insert language parameter as xx or xx-YY. It needs to work for both

- If `xx-YY` is not available, site should provide `xx` (mother country language) results.
- if `xx` is not available, site should provide `en` (English) results.

Example of URL to be supported:

```
http://website.domain/fr-YY/...

  fall-back to: http://website.domain/fr/...

http://website.domain/xx/...

  fall-back to: http://website.domain/en/...
```

Example URL from Mozilla site:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/949545

How to make Django support IETF language tag (xx-YY format)? I'm looking even for hints to implement this without modifying the django upstream code.

**Update:**

Well, official documentation says clearly it should fall-back (ex: en-us to en) but my case raises 404 error.

Source: https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.x/topics/i18n/translation.html

> If a base language is available but the sublanguage specified is not, Django uses the base language. For example, if a user specifies de-at (Austrian German) but Django only has de available, Django uses de.
>
> ...
>
> LANGUAGES = (
>     ('de', _('German')),
>     ('en', _('English')),
>   )
>
> This example restricts languages that are available for automatic selection to German and English (and any sublanguage, like de-ch or en-us).

Here are related code portions:

**`settings.py`**

```
# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = (
  ( 'ar', "Arabic" ),
  ( 'en', "English" ),
  ( 'fr', "French" ),
  ( 'id', "Indonesian" ),
  ( 'ja', "Japanese"),
  ( 'ku', "Kurdish" ),
  #( 'ur', "Urdu" ),
  ( 'ms', "Malay" ),
  ( 'ml', "Malayalam" ),
  #( 'tr', "Turkish" ),
  ( 'es', "Spanish" ),
  ( 'pt', "Portuguese"),
  #( 'sv', "swedish" )
)

# These are languages not supported by Django core. We have to provide
# their info here so we can use them in our templates. This is mainly
# used in `wui.templatetags.languages`.
EXTRA_LANGUAGES = {
  'ku': {
    'code': 'ku',
    'name': 'Kurdish',
    'bidi': True,
    'name_local': 'Kurdish'
  },
  'ms': {
    'code': 'ms',
    'name': 'Malay',
    'bidi': False,
    'name_local': 'Malay'
  },
}


SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True
```

**`urls.py`**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns( '',
  url( r'^jos2', 'wui.views.jos2' ),
  url(r'^r', 'wui.views.one_aya_page'),
  url(r'^$', 'wui.views.results'),
  # url( r'^admin/', include( admin.site.urls ) ),
)

# These URLs accept the language prefix.
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
  url(r'^$', 'wui.views.results'),
  url(r'^(?P<unit>\w{3,15})/', 'wui.views.results'),
)

# 404 not found handler

handler404 = 'wui.views.custom_404'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as far I can test, Django i18n does supports fall-back `xx-YY` to `xx` then to default (`en` in my case) but only for `Accept-Language` user agent header. It does not do same for URL language switch.

Here is the solution I could come up with:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.conf import settings
...
urlpatterns += patterns('',
  url(r'^(?P<lang>[a-z]{2})-[A-Za-z]{2}/(?P<path>.*)$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/%(lang)s/%(path)s',query_string=True)),
  url(r'^[a-z]{2}/(?P<path>.*)$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/{}/%(path)s'.format(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE),query_string=True)),
)
```

- Any `xx-YY` not handled by i18n pattern redirected to `xx`
- Any `xx` not handled by i18n pattern redirected to default language set using `LANGUAGE_CODE`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the supported languages in your settings:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English'),
    ('en-gb', _('British English'),
    ('en-au', _('Australian English'),
    ('es', _('Spanish'),
    ('es-ar', _('Argentinian Spanish'),
)
```

From there, use `i18n_urlpatterns`. When you create PO files, you will need to run `python manage.py makemessages -l en_GB`, etc. Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/) for more information.

Comment: But i don't want to create separate translation for `en-gb` , i just want it to display `en` instead of any `en-??`. Doc says that django should take care of that, so may be something wrong in my setup. I will update my question with related code portions.

Comment: If you only want `en`, then only generate a PO file for `en`. The code will fall back to using `en` for both `en_AU` and `en_GB`. `python manage.py makemessages -l en`

Comment: slurms, my still raise  404 error for any `en-??` lang like `en-us`, I expect bug in my urls.py setup for i18n. I added the related code to the question, could you please make a look on it.

Comment: You have to make sure the variant is included in `LANGUAGES`. It looks like you're just defining `en`, and not `en-gb` or `en-au`. You could always make your own version of `i18n_urlpatterns` that does something very similar, but always activates the non-variant language `language_code.split('-')[0]` or something.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Django uses  fall-back on `Accept-Language` from user agent header but not on URL language switch. I end up add my own URL redirections.