# how to convert a Django project to Malay (Malaysia) language? Tried using ugettext_lazy but it is only supporting popular languages

Tags: django, translation

I tried gettext_lazy and am a able to convert the admin page into Spanish, French, Arabic, etc. But when I try with malay using the code ms, nothing is happening.

Comment: Django doesn't have Malay. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801008/how-to-make-django-support-ietf-language-tag-xx-yy-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801008/how-to-make-django-support-ietf-language-tag-xx-yy-format)

Comment: Also list of available languages - [https://github.com/django/django/blob/de4492fbb1e48f8b258baa182220d4247f345177/django/conf/global_settings.py#L51](https://github.com/django/django/blob/de4492fbb1e48f8b258baa182220d4247f345177/django/conf/global_settings.py#L51)

Answer (score 0):

Django 4.0 is out there and it now supports the Malay language. Please have a look at [Internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#internationalization) on [Django 4.0 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/).

> **Internationalization**
>
> - Added support and translations for the Malay language.